# Increment or decrement app badge while app in terminated state

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have got push notification working and managed to update icon badge count when app is brought to foreground.

But i want to update icon badge when app is terminate state.

I know that when app in terminated state then badge count depend on push notification payload as:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9
    }
}
```

So, it show 9 icon badge

**NOTE**: But I want to know, how backend will handle to increment or decrement or make badge count zero.

Comment: just set the badge count 0 in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and hit API that is for updating badge count !

Comment: It's not duplicate because there are not show any logic to resolve badge icon update issue

Answer (score 5):

**You can't.**
You have to keep track of your badge value server side and send a payload with the incremented/decremented value.

Comment: This is one of the most recent posts about this (it's been mostly 2013 questions/answers), and wow, I can't believe this is still a thing. iOS let's you completely overwrite a new badge value, but it won't allow you to increment it by 1 when you receive a new notification. This makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @Merricat, How you will increment badge in terminated app?. Quentin Hayot you are right.

Comment: @Merricat unfortunately, this is still a thing !

Comment: Yes, it's a bit of a sad inconvenience. @VikasRajput I don't increment my badge in terminated state. On the backend I keep track of all the notifications for each user, so when a notification is pushed, I send the total count, which is actually less error-prone (forces client and server to stay in sync at the cost of recalculating its value everytime)